# Python - Check every other week using if statement

Tags: python, date, if-statement, calendar

I have the following if statement:

`if date.weekday() != 0:`

How can I change this if statement to check every other Monday (one day every other week)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You post doesn't mention what language you're using. That would be useful to know!

At any rate, a function like `weekday` probably returns a number from 0-6, which isn't going to give you enough info.

Most languages have a function that turns a date into a millisecond value, typically milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC.

If you take such a value and divide it by 86400000 (number of milliseconds in a day), you get a day number. Day 0 (January 1, 1970) happens to be a Thursday.

In JavaScript, this day number can be obtained from a `Date` object like this:

`let dayNum = Math.floor(someDate.getTime() / 86400000)`

From this, `dayNum % 7` gives you a number from 0-6 for Thursday through Wednesday. You can add an offset to change what 0 means. `(dayNum + 4) % 7` produces 0-6 for Sunday through Saturday.

You want a 14-day cycle for every other week, so `dayNum % 14` is what you need, and you then just have to decide which value from 0 to 13 represents your target dates.

Take any sample date that is one of your desired dates, compute the remainder value you get for that date, and then test for that value to be able to match any qualifying date.

Two caveats:

1. For dates before 1970, the `%` operator might produces negative numbers. Python is  one of the few languages that doesn't do this.
2. The timezone offset from UTC might be important to your task. And if that's important, Daylight Saving Time changes and/or historical changes in UTC offset can complicate matters.

Python update:

Let's say this coming Monday (July 5, 2021) is one of the every-other-week days that you want. This:

`date(2021, 7, 5).toordinal() % 14`

...produces a value of 8. Every other Monday before or after will also be 8. The `toordinal()` method goes straight to a day number, without having to fuss with milliseconds, 86400000, or having to worry about timezone offsets.

Comment: I am using Python.  Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: I'll add to my answer with a Python-specific solution.

Comment: Did the Python version help? (If so, please up-vote!)